# Ограничить доступ к сайту

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Кто знает, как можно ограничить доступ к своему сайту(кроме логина и пароля). Допустим у меня есть сайт, где работают пользователи(у каждого свои учетные данные). Но на сайте есть конфиденциальная инфа. Нужно сделать так, чтобы сайт не открывался нигде кроме офиса, IP - динамический.

P.S. забыл указать, сайт должен быть доступен через интернет, т.к. будет работать не только в одной компании.

P.S.(2) задумывался сделать ограничение по ip, но чтобы с офисного сервера при изменении отправлялся IP на сервер, но как это реализовать? Либо как-то по сертификатам?

Comment: Создай свою точку доступа (Wi-Fi роутер), запусти на нём сайт, **а порты не открывай, чтобы сайт был доступен только в локальной сети.** И заставь пользователей *коннектиться* к твоему Wi-Fi для доступа к сайту. Таким образом, к сайту (и, соответственно, к конфиденциальной информации на нём) будут иметь доступ только те устройства, которые подключены к твоей Wi-Fi сети.

Comment: забыл указать, сайт должен быть доступен через интернет, т.к. будет работать не только в одной компании

Comment: Есть у меня одна идея, возможно, не самая лучшая на мой взгляд. Допустим, сайт запущен где-то на хостинге. В каждом офисе можно поставить Wi-Fi роутеры, каждый должен иметь статический IP-адрес. Пользователям для доступа к сайту необходимо подключиться к Wi-Fi сети офиса, чтобы зайти на сайт. Соответственно, на сайте нужно прописать все эти статические IP-адреса Wi-Fi роутеров, и доступен сайт будет только пользователям, подключившимся к одной из этих Wi-Fi сетей. *ну хотя не очень идея, это мне первое в голову пришло.. и единственное.*

Comment: Для своего офиса возможно подойдет, а другие врядли захотят это делать:)

Comment: Это называется VPN

Comment: можно подробнее, что мне сделать с vpn?)

Comment: Обычно для таких задач пишут клиент серверное приложение, с сертификатами и авторизацией (по железу, сертификату, логину паролю) так называемый сайт - это удалённая база данных доступ к которой получают только после авторизации. Взаимодействие организовывают на Socket-ах.

Comment: Сперва, надо начать с того: чем левые люди отличаются от своих. Вы говорите чтоб сперва чтоб нигде кроме офиса, потом что по интернету, а потом что еще и другие будут им пользоваться -.- Если и другие будут пользоваться, то логин и пароль, все что у вас остается, либо контролировать ипы.

Comment: @Manitikyl, ну или может геолокацию *набилдить* по GPS, чтоб чётко только в здании доступ был к сайту :D